# Arduino output pins go HIGH on start?

Tags: serial-port, usb, arduino

i have an [AceDuino](http://www.alexan.com.ph/index.php/training-modules/226-aceduino-328) board similar to Arduino. i tried to making a sample LED and a button using this [Demo](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Pushbutton). I had notice that when i plug the USB, the LED will flashing a couple of times.

just wanna ask if this is normal when using a USB to power the arduino.

is there any way i can avoid it?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The onboard LED (pin 13) flashes a couple of times [to indicate that the Arduino is executing the bootloader](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/bootloaders/atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168.c#L423). This will happen every time you power or reset the board.

You can avoid it by modifying the bootloader inside your Arduino board. But this will require an AVR In-System Programmer (a piece of hardware that program microcontrollers) to burn the bootloader. You can also use another Arduino board with a special sketch as an AVR In-System Programmer.

[This link](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/247) explains how to implement both approaches to burn the Arduino Uno's bootloader (which uses the same microcontroller of your clone).

My advice: avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 1):

To go a little further that borges, the bled is blinking because of the Arduino reset due to the serial communication established between your computer and the board via USB.

it's very useful because you know your board is working properly.

As Tomato said, you can avoid using pin 13 for you test but you need an extra led to plug to which ever pin you want and you then need to modify the code `ledPin = 13;`

If you don't have an extra led, pin 13 refers to the onboard led that you see blinking at the beginning. Juste wait till the board has started and it will work!

Hope it helps,
Cheers.